# Expectation of an exponential uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

This may sound basic but I am not sure and cannot find any well-sourced properties of the expectation that would allow me to be.

$\alpha$ is a real parameter strictly greater than zero. And, $v$ is a random variable continuously distributed according to a Uniform distribution over 0, 1.

Doest the last equality indeed holds? If not, what would be the result?

$$ \mathbb{E} \left( \alpha \cdot e^{\frac{-v}{\alpha}}\right) = \alpha \cdot \mathbb{E}\left( e^{\frac{-v}{\alpha}} \right) =  \alpha \cdot e^{\frac{-\mathbb{E}\left( v\right)}{\alpha}}$$

Where $\mathbb{E}$ is the expected value, and $e$ the exponential function $exp ()$.

Thank you,

Comment: It does not hold. In general we do **not** have $\mathbb Ef(X)=f(\mathbb EX)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality), your last equality is clearly an inequality, thus

$$\alpha\mathbb{E}[e^{-v/\alpha}]\geq \alpha e^{-\mathbb{E}[V]/\alpha}$$

If you want to calculate it correctly just use the definition of expectation that is

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)])=\int g(x) f(x)dx=\alpha\int_0^1e^{-v/\alpha}dv=\alpha^2(1-e^{-1/\alpha})$$

which is clearly greater than $\alpha \cdot e^{-1/(2\alpha)}$

Comment: Of course... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$E\alpha e^{-\frac v {\alpha}}=\int_0^{1} \alpha e^{-\frac x {\alpha}}dx=\alpha^{2}[1-e^{-\frac 1 {\alpha}}]$.